# Acyclic undirected graph allocation problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, greedy, graph-traversal

We have an allocation problem: each node is a fuel source, and every edge contains a number of evenly spaced out lamps (think of them as being 1 m apart from each other). Each fuel source can power lamps that are on the immediate edges around it (it cannot fuel lamps through other nodes). A fuel source also has a radius in which it fuels lamps around it - depending on the radius (in meters) we can calculate the amount of fuel a give fuel source provides - example: a fuel source with a radius of 2 can fuel all the lamps within its radius and, in total, uses up 2 liters of fuel (fuel usage is a function of the radius).

Note that two nodes have only one path between each other (meaning that that the number of edges is equal to the number of nodes - 1).

The goal is to calculate the optimal radii of the fuel sources so that we minimize the fuel usage while fueling all the lamps.

[Here is an example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vpg0e.png)

The solution to this graph looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxcdl.png). The red ellipsoids are supposed to visualize the radii of the fuel sources, and below is a table of the relevant values:

| Node, fuel source | Radius, fuel consumption |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 |

After we add up all the fuel amounts, we get the result: **5**.

The input for the above task looks like this:

```
6     // 6 nodes (numVertices)
0 1 3 // Node 0 with an edge containing 3 nodes going to node 3 (src dest lights)
1 2 1 // ...
2 3 2
1 4 2
1 5 2
```

So far I've tried loading up my edges like this (note that this solution is quite cursed, especially with my use of pointers):

```cpp
struct light {
    int count;
};

struct node {
    int d;
    light* l;
};

std::vector<node*>* tree;
int numVertices;

// Do this for all values in the input
void AddEdge(int src, int dest, int lights) {
        light* l = new light{ lights };
        tree[src].push_back(new node{ dest, l });
        tree[dest].push_back(new node{ src, l });
}
```

And then I solved the graph by using a greedy algorithm to 'remove' as many lamps per step as possible:

```cpp
void Solve() {
    int fuel = 0;

    while (true) {
        int maxNode = 0;
        int maxNodeLights = 0;

        for (int A = 0; A < numVertices; A++)
        {
            int lightsOnNode = 0;

            for (node* B : tree[A])
            {
                lightsOnNode += B->l->count;
            }

            if (lightsOnNode > maxNodeLights) {
                maxNodeLights = lightsOnNode;
                maxNode = A;
            }
        }

        if (maxNodeLights > 0) {
            bool addedRange = false;

            for (node* B : tree[maxNode])
            {
                if (B->l->count > 0) {
                    B->l->count--;
                    addedRange = true;
                }
            }

            if (addedRange) {
                fuel++;
            }
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << fuel << '\n';
}
```

If we were to parse the input string from the example case it would look like this:

```cpp
numVertices = 6;

AddEdge(0, 1, 3);
AddEdge(1, 2, 1);
AddEdge(2, 3, 2);
AddEdge(1, 4, 2);
AddEdge(1, 5, 2);

Solve();
```

This works for simple graphs like the one above, but it fails by a small margin once a more complex graph is introduced, since the greedy algorithm doesn't look ahead if there is a better option a couple steps in the future.

A long test case can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/vV0tMKBh). The fuel amount consumed by this graph is 77481.

New, failing test cases:

```
1 0 4
2 1 1
3 2 4
4 3 1
5 1 2
6 1 1
7 2 2
8 3 2
9 1 1
10 1 3
11 5 1
12 0 2
13 10 4
14 3 3
15 5 4
```

(Output: 16. Correct output: 17)

```
1 0 2
2 1 3
3 2 2
4 1 4
5 4 3
6 3 2
7 5 3
8 3 4
```

(Output: 10. Correct output: 11)

```
1 0 4
2 0 3
3 0 4
4 3 3
5 2 2
6 3 1
7 2 1
8 3 2
9 3 2
10 2 1
11 9 1
12 4 2
13 5 2
14 8 2
15 9 1
16 14 2
17 3 3
18 3 4
```

(Output: 15. Correct output: 16)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/74420724/16582

Comment: Yes, it seems like multiple people are posting their homework on SO.

Comment: Odd how the same problem is being presented with different terminology.

Comment: @MarkB it's close to the end of the semester. This happens periodically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithm pseudocode:

- WHILE lamps remain unfueled

  - LOOP over sources

    - IF source has exactly one edge with unfueled lamps

      - SET fuel source to source at other end of unfueled edge
      - INCREMENT radius of fuel source with unfueled edge lamp count
      - LOOP over edges on fuel source

        - IF edge fueled lamp count from fuel sourve < fuel source radius

          - SET edge fueled lamp count from fuel source to fuel source radius

C++ code for this is at https://github.com/JamesBremner/LampLighter.

#### Sample output

```
Input
0 1 1
1 2 1
2 3 1
3 4 1
0 5 1
5 6 1
6 7 1
7 8 1
0 9 1
9 10 1
10 11 1
11 12 1

Source radii
0 r=0
1 r=1
2 r=0
3 r=1
4 r=0
5 r=1
6 r=0
7 r=1
8 r=0
9 r=1
10 r=0
11 r=1
12 r=0

Total fuel 6
```

#### Handling different numbers of lamps on each edge

```
0 1 3
1 2 1
0 5 3
5 6 1

Source radius
0 r=2
1 r=1
2 r=0
5 r=1
6 r=0

Total fuel 4
```

#### Another test

```
lamp ..\test\data11_19_2.txt
```

Output:

```
1 0 2
2 1 3
3 2 2
4 1 4
5 4 3
6 3 2
7 5 3
8 3 4

Source radius
1 r=3
0 r=0
2 r=0
3 r=4
4 r=0
5 r=3
6 r=0
7 r=0
8 r=0

Total fuel 10
```

Acknowledgement:  This algorithm is based on an insight from [MarkB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17841694/markb) who suggested that fueling should begin at leaf nodes and work "downwards"

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249759/discussion-on-answer-by-ravenspoint-acyclic-undirected-graph-allocation-problem).